# How to grab http and mailto links in regex

Tags: php, regex, email

I'm trying to fix a bug on a WP Plugin. It uses this expression to parse the urls:

`$anchorPattern = '/\'\"\/\/([^\'\"]+?)\'\">(.*?)</a>/i';`

The problem is with the mailto: urls, which are not being matched correctly. 
So for example, when the code is like:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com" target="_blank"><img src="email.png"></a>
```

The 2nd match is

`mailto:email@email.com" target="_blank"><img src="http:`

because the regex only stops at the //. How to I change the regex expression to get the 2nd match to be 'mailto:' ?

regex testing here: http://regex101.com/r/sY4bW8

Comment: How about using `DOM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your regex as follows:

`<a (.*?)href=[\'\"](.*?:)([^\'\"]+?)[\'\"](.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>`

Now it will match `mailto:`.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mM4bT3)

Comment: Thank you! That's almost what I need! In this case the third match for a normal url would be something like '//url.com'.Is it possible to get only the 'url.com' (without the //) in the third match for a url and 'email@email.com' for a mailto?

Answer (score 1):

Vê se é isso que vc quer:

```
preg_match('/<a.*?href=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?><img.*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?>/i', $html)
```

**Grupo 1 é o url**
**Grupo 2 a source da imagem.**

http://regex101.com/r/dR5cQ6